# Uncalibrated multi-view reconstruction depth estimation

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, 3d-reconstruction, projective-geometry

I'm trying to make a 3D reconstruction from a set of uncalibrated photographs in MATLAB. I use SIFT to detect feature points and matches between images. I want to make a projective reconstruction first and then update this to a metric one using auto-calibration.

I know how to estimate the 3D points from 2 images by computing the fundamental matrix, camera matrices and triangulation. Now say I have 3 images, a, b and c. I compute the camera matrices and 3D points for image a and b. Now I want to update the structure by adding image c. I estimate the camera matrix by using known 3D points (calculated from a and b) that match with 2D points in image c, since:

[image]

However when I reconstruct the 3D points between b and c they don't add up with the existing 3D points from a and b. I'm assuming this is because I don't know the correct depth estimates of the points (depicted by *s* in above formula).

With the [factorization method of Sturm and Triggs](http://www.vision.jhu.edu/reading_group/sturm96factorization.pdf) I can estimate the depths and find the structure and motion. However in order to do this, all points have to be visible in all views, which is not the case for my images. How can I estimate the depths for points not visible in all views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a question about Matlab. It is about an algorithm.

It is not mathematically possible to estimate the position of a 3D point in an image when you don't see an observation of the point in said image.

There are extensions for factorization to work with missing data. However, the field seems to have converged to [Bundle Adjustment](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00548290/PDF/Triggs-va99.pdf) as the Gold Standard.

An excellent tutorial on how to achieve what you want can be found [here](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~marc/tutorial/), which is a culmination of several years of research into a working application. Starting from projective reconstruction up to the metric upgrade.